# Use default implementation in my own "UITableViewController" to make methods optional

Tags: c#, ios, inheritance, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've written my own implementation of `UIViewController` in Xamarin.iOS:

```
public class HUDTableViewController : UIViewController, IUITableViewDataSource, IUITableViewDelegate, IDisposable
{
    private UITableView tableView;

    public UITableView TableView
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tableView;
        }
        set
        {
            this.tableView = value;
        }
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        this.tableView = new UITableView();
        this.tableView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

        this.tableView.WeakDelegate = this;
        this.tableView.WeakDataSource = this;

        UIView parentView = new UIView();
        parentView.AddSubview(this.tableView);
        View = parentView;

        NSMutableDictionary viewsDictionary = new NSMutableDictionary();
        viewsDictionary["parent"] = parentView;
        viewsDictionary["tableView"] = this.tableView;

        parentView.AddConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("H:|[tableView]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
        parentView.AddConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("V:|[tableView]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
    }

    [Foundation.Export("numberOfSectionsInTableView:")]
    public virtual System.nint NumberOfSections(UIKit.UITableView tableView)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual System.nint RowsInSection(UIKit.UITableView tableview, System.nint section)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual UIKit.UITableViewCell GetCell(UIKit.UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [Foundation.Export("tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:")]
    public virtual void RowSelected(UIKit.UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [Foundation.Export("tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:")]
    public virtual System.nfloat GetHeightForHeader(UIKit.UITableView tableView, System.nint section)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [Foundation.Export("tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:")]
    public virtual UIKit.UIView GetViewForHeader(UIKit.UITableView tableView, System.nint section)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [Foundation.Export("tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:")]
    public virtual void WillDisplay(UIKit.UITableView tableView, UIKit.UITableViewCell cell, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now I want to use that class and derive from it. One of the derivations needs `GetHeightForHeader` and `GetViewForHeader`, the other not. The one which doesn't need it seems also to call this functions and I get `NotImplementedException` exception.

I don't know what it triggers so that the methods are called. I can implement `GetHeightForHeader` and return `UITableView.AutomaticDimension`, but what should I do with `GetViewForHeader`?

How can I make this class flexible enough so that all derivations can make use of it and only call the methods they need? What should I put in the methods instead of `throw new NotImplementedException();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply don't implement them. I haven't used Xamarin, but these methods look to be from `IUITableViewDataSource` and `IUITableViewDelegate` - meaning they are called by table view at appropriate times. In Cocoa only two methods from these two protocols are marked as required, from your example it would be these two :

```
public virtual System.nint RowsInSection(UIKit.UITableView tableview, System.nint section);
public virtual UIKit.UITableViewCell GetCell(UIKit.UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath);
```

The rest is entirely optional, so there is no need for a default implementation, as table view already knows how to handle it, when they are not implemented.

Judging from these [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.IUITableViewDataSource/), it seems that things are also pretty similar in Xamarin, as only the two mentioned methods are marked as `IsRequired=true`.

If you insist on having these implementations, then you should return as neutral values as possible. What is "neutral" in this case is another thing and up for debate. It may be `0` for header height and `nil` for its view for example, but rather a `44` for cells height. At least these are the default values in Cocoa.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, only these two methods are required. If I remove my virtual methods I get *NumberOfSections(UIKit.UITableView) is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override (CS0115)*. I get rid of this error if I remove the `override`. Then I have for example `public nint NumberOfSections (UITableView tableView)` in my derived class. That does compile, but then my headers for example are completely missing, some sections are missing and so on. So the methods in the derived class are not called anymore. What do I have to add?

Comment: You'd have to implement the appropriate methods. If you want a section header then `GetHeightForHeader` and `GetViewForHeader` are the ones to use. In case of missing sections, the default value is `1`. If you want to have more sections, you should implement `NumberOfSections` and return a correct value there.

Comment: Have you looked through the [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/)?

Comment: Some time ago ;-) What I can remember there was only general things about using `UITableViewController` and not the special case here. But I can have another look. Regarding your other message: The methods are implemented (without `override`), but they are not called. Because the default value for the number of sections is `1`, I can only see the first section.

Comment: [Similar implementations](https://github.com/xamarin/dev-days-labs/blob/master/Demos/TwitterSearch/TwitterSearch.iOS/RootViewController.cs) directly implement the methods in the base class (in my case in the `HUDTableViewController`). They are not deriving from it. So the method calls need to be passed further and at the same time be optional. How can this be done in C#/.NET?

Comment: That I unfortuantelly don't know. It seems that someone better versed in Xamarin/C#/.NET could better help you.

Comment: I think I got it now. I did what you said and returned the correct default values if necessary instad of throwing `NotImplementedException`. Despite some small [issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34263376/where-should-i-put-my-setup-so-that-the-derived-class-has-everything-loaded-at-t) it seems to work. What I still don't fully understand is when `GetHeightForHeader`, `GetViewForHeader`, `EstimatedHeight` is called. Are they automatically called if I implement `TitleForHeader`? Nevertheless, I give you the tick because you were the most helpful here!

Comment: It actually shouldn't matter to you `when` they are called - these are implementation details, and not important in general case. You should only need to care whether you need them, and if so, what to return from them. For example, the `titleForHeader` has a [fixed font style](http://apple.co/221tptN), so if you want something custom, you should rather use the [`getViewForHeader`](http://apple.co/1YeHizP) and [`getHeightForHeader`](http://apple.co/1mjFTwg)